# Python Pandas - Read Table with Show More Button

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to python, just trying to analyze some websites.

I am trying to pull the table from this website:

https://www.espn.com/nhl/stats/player

I tried to use the below code. It worked, but it does not capture the data after the show more button in the website. Is there a way I can do that? I did see some documentation on selenium, but I do not quite understand how to use it in this application.

```
players_list_unclean = pd.read_html('https://www.sportsnet.ca/hockey/nhl/players/?season=2021&?seasonType=reg&tab=Skaters') ``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're new to python and web scraping, I'd suggest trying out static sites such as wikipedia.

Also the link you provided doesn't match the url you used in the code.

The code you have here doesn't work because that table is rendered by javascript, so the initial request doesn't have any `<table>` tags (or for espn site, just has the initial table). You can get the data directly through an api for espn, or that other site. I found the url by going to Dev Tools (sfht-ctrl-i) and going to Network -> XHR to see what requests are made.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://mobile-statsv2.sportsnet.ca/web_player_table?league=nhl&season=2021&season_type=reg'
jsonData = requests.get(url).json()
data = jsonData['data']

skaters_players_list_unclean = pd.json_normalize(data, 
                                         record_path=['player_stats', 'skaters'])

goalies_players_list_unclean = pd.json_normalize(data, 
                                         record_path=['player_stats', 'goalies'])
```

**Output:**

```
print(skaters_players_list_unclean)
     player_id player_name_formatted  ... last_name position
0      1214439           Ahcan, Jack  ...     Ahcan        D
1       230685     Bergeron, Patrice  ...  Bergeron        C
2       745313          Blidh, Anton  ...     Blidh       LW
3       878156        Carlo, Brandon  ...     Carlo        D
4       744943       Clifton, Connor  ...   Clifton        D
..         ...                   ...  ...       ...      ...
944     550771        Sheahan, Riley  ...   Sheahan       LW
945     744948         Soucy, Carson  ...     Soucy        D
946     913797        Tanev, Brandon  ...     Tanev       RW
947    1078266       True, Alexander  ...      True        C
948     741444        Wennberg, Alex  ...  Wennberg        C

[949 rows x 24 columns]


print(goalies_players_list_unclean)
     player_id player_name_formatted  ... last_name position
0       300802          Rask, Tuukka  ...      Rask        G
1      1057221       Swayman, Jeremy  ...   Swayman        G
2       681544        Ullmark, Linus  ...   Ullmark        G
3       176834       Anderson, Craig  ...  Anderson        G
4       826521           Dell, Aaron  ...      Dell        G
..         ...                   ...  ...       ...      ...
104     521575         Lehner, Robin  ...    Lehner        G
105    1139760       Thompson, Logan  ...  Thompson        G
106     878403         Daccord, Joey  ...   Daccord        G
107     680662       Driedger, Chris  ...  Driedger        G
108     555124     Grubauer, Philipp  ...  Grubauer        G

[109 rows x 25 columns]
```

**For ESPN:**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/common/v3/sports/hockey/nhl/statistics/byathlete'
payload = {
'region': 'us',
'lang': 'en',
'contentorigin': 'espn',
'isqualified': 'false',
'page': '1',
'limit': '999',
'sort': 'offensive:points:desc',
'category': 'skaters'}
jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
data = jsonData['athletes']

players_list_unclean = pd.json_normalize(data)
```

**Output:**

```
print(players_list_unclean)
                                            categories  ... athlete.teamUId
0    [{'name': 'general', 'displayName': 'Own Gener...  ...   s:70~l:90~t:6
1    [{'name': 'general', 'displayName': 'Own Gener...  ...  s:70~l:90~t:26
2    [{'name': 'general', 'displayName': 'Own Gener...  ...   s:70~l:90~t:6
3    [{'name': 'general', 'displayName': 'Own Gener...  ...  s:70~l:90~t:21
4    [{'name': 'general', 'displayName': 'Own Gener...  ...  s:70~l:90~t:17
..                                                 ...  ...             ...
944  [{'name': 'general', 'displayName': 'Own Gener...  ...  s:70~l:90~t:26
945  [{'name': 'general', 'displayName': 'Own Gener...  ...  s:70~l:90~t:21
946  [{'name': 'general', 'displayName': 'Own Gener...  ...   s:70~l:90~t:1
947  [{'name': 'general', 'displayName': 'Own Gener...  ...  s:70~l:90~t:25
948  [{'name': 'general', 'displayName': 'Own Gener...  ...  s:70~l:90~t:24

[949 rows x 31 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very clear!